# WPF Binding TwoWay not working, OneWayToSource working. WHY?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, two-way

I have a control with a DependencyProperty of type TimeSpan. When I try to bind to that property, the value is not being updated.

Usage of the control:

```
<controls:TimeControl Time={Binding SomeTimeSpanProperty} />
```

When I change the value of the Time in the Control, the change is not updated in the SomeTimeSpanProperty. However, if I change the *{Binding SomeTimeSpanProperty}* to *{Binding SomeTimeSpanProperty,Mode=OneWayToSource}*, it is updated.

Comment: Why so much downwotes? What exactly is/was wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If anyone reading this in the future wants to know what was it:

I had to explicitly set the mode of the binding to TwoWay, because the default binding mode for the TimeSpan type property is OneWay.

from this:

```
<controls:TimeControl Time={Binding SomeTimeSpanProperty} />
```

to this:

```
<controls:TimeControl Time={Binding SomeTimeSpanProperty,Mode=TwoWay} />
```

And now it **works**!

Comment: In WPF, the default value of the `Binding.Mode` property is [`BindingMode.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx). This may sound funny, but it means that the Binding "*uses the default Mode value of the binding target. The default value varies for each dependency property. In general, user-editable control properties, such as those of text boxes and check boxes, default to two-way bindings, whereas most other properties default to one-way bindings.*"